# How do I get user input from a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am attempting a *very* simple form designed to take user input into a JTextField and show that same input via a pop up dialog.

I can hardcode the JTextField to have a preset number using setText(). If I do this, my program works flawlessly.

However, when I leave the field blank and try getText() to show the text in the pop up dialog, I either get an empty pop up frame, or I get an 'empty string' exception (I am attempting to parse String to Double.)

`package buttontest;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;



public class ButtonTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
    @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
    public ButtonFrame()
    {


                setTitle("SunStream Loan Calculator v2.0");
        setSize(900,900);
        ButtonPanel panel = new ButtonPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter your loan amount:"));
                loanAmt = new JTextField(40);
                panel.add(loanAmt);

                add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


        public JTextField loanAmt;

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private Component frame;
    public ButtonPanel()
    {

                final JButton b2 = new JButton("Calculate");
        add(b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                b2.setActionCommand("calculate");
                b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                              ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
                              if("calculate".equals(e.getActionCommand()))
                                {
                                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, bf.loanAmt.getText());
                                }
                        }

    });

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }


  }
}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am researching using a KeyListener or KeyEvent but I don't quite understand it well enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're creating a "shadow" ButtonFrame variable inside of the b2's ActionListener. Yes the bf variable refers to a ButtonFrame object which is of the same class as the displayed ButtonFrame object, but it refers to a completely distinct and non-visualized object. The key to a solution is to get the text from the ButtonFrame object that is actually displayed, and this can be obtained from within an inner class via the `ButtonFrame.this` construct:

```
     b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           //!! ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
           if ("calculate".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {

              //!! note use of ButtonFrame.this:
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, ButtonFrame.this.loanAmt.getText());
           }
        }

     });
```

Next consider using public getters rather than accessing fields such as the JTextField directly. This reduces the chances of the code causing side effects, such as changing the properties of the JTextField object inadvertently.

For instance (changes denoted by //!! comment):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class ButtonTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class ButtonFrame extends JFrame {

   private JTextField loanAmt; // !! Make field private

   @SuppressWarnings("LeakingThisInConstructor")
   public ButtonFrame() {

      setTitle("SunStream Loan Calculator v2.0");
      setSize(900, 900);
      ButtonPanel panel = new ButtonPanel();
      panel.add(new JLabel("Enter your loan amount:"));
      loanAmt = new JTextField(40);
      panel.add(loanAmt);

      add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   // !! create a public method to get JTextField's text
   // !! without exposing the JTextField itself.
   public String getLoanAmtText() {
      return loanAmt.getText();
   }

   class ButtonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
      private Component frame;

      public ButtonPanel() {

         final JButton b2 = new JButton("Calculate");
         add(b2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         b2.setActionCommand("calculate");
         b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               // !! ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
               if ("calculate".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {

                  //!! call public method on ButtonFrame object
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        ButtonFrame.this.getLoanAmtText());
               }
            }

         });

      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
         throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: This was SO helpful! Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it!

Comment: You're quite welcome! Best of luck on this project and on your Java studies!

Comment: @Phoenix: the key here is it's all about *references*. You need a reference to the actual displayed object, not any ButtonFrame object. The more you understand references and reference variables, the better you will understand Java and OOPs.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I was beating my head against a wall trying to understand it. So when creating 3 new text fields, I'll need to reference each displayed object (ButtonFrame1.this -- ButtonFrame2.this -- ButtonFrame3.this) in order to do anything with them. I am attempting to make a simple amortization calculator

Comment: @Phoenix: No, my guess is not. If you have three JTextFields and they're all held in the same class, ButtonFrame, then you'll only need a reference to the one ButtonFrame object, ButtonFrame.this. You'll then either need three accessor methods to get text from the three JTextFields or else one accessor method that takes a parameter that somehow keys the method as to which JTextField's text to return.

Comment: Oh, okay I see. In order to keep it simple (for now anyway) I may just create 3 accessor methods from each individual field (ButtonFrame.this.getLoanAmountText() -- ButtonFrame.this.getLoanRateText() -- ButtonFrame.this.getLoanTermText()) where each method returns the values from the individual text fields. Again, thank you so much. This was such a great help!!

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can access your **loanAmt** is through **ButtonPanel** itself. Because you add **loanAmt** to this button right ?

So, if you want access **loanAmt**. You must get all component on this button panel. This is my psudeo code howto accessing your **loanAmt** from ButtonPanel class.

```
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ButtonFrame bf = new ButtonFrame();
        if("calculate".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            // Get all component 
            java.awt.Component[] componentList = this.getComponents();
            JTextField txtField;
            String value;
            for (int i = 0; i < componentList.length; i++) {
                if (componentList[i].getClass().getName().equals("javax.swing.JTextField")) {
                    txtField = (JTextField) componentList[i];
                    value = textField.getText();
                }
            }
            if (value != null) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, value);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And what if the JTextField is nested inside JPanels that are nested inside of other JPanels? And what if the layout of the GUI later changes? And what if the GUI has multiple JTextFields? No, this is a very fragile way of extracting information will easily break and does not scale well. It's better to use public accessor methods. Even better but more advanced ways are described [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364562/Java-GUI-Development-Reintroducing-MVC) and [here](http://javadude.com/articles/vaddmvc2/mvc2.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah its nightmare if the JTextField located inside nested Panel. I agree with your solution :)

Comment: I edited your post (added a space) so I could un-do my down-vote. I recommend that you read the links in my comment above as they're nothing short of amazing and really opened my eyes. They put my recommendations in my answer to shame.